# Is there a way for me to use a template from an html file and use it on bootstrap modal?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So, here's the deal, I dont want to put this, because I think it's really tacky and confusing.:

```
function showModal(title, body) {
    var html = '<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">' +
    '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
    '<div class="modal-content">' +
    '<div class="modal-header">' +
    '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>' +
    '<h4 class="modal-title">' + title + '</h4>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="modal-body">' +
    '<p>' + body + '</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="modal-footer">' +
    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>' +
    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';

    var modal = $(html);
    modal.modal("show");
}
```

What I want to happen is, remove the contents of `var html` and save it in a separate html file and just load the thing `.modal(show)`. Is there a way to do that with jquery? the quotes and plus signs could easily get messy and I dont want that. Sorry if it's a bit of a noob question.

Comment: You can use a js template engine like mustache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really easy. save your modal html codes in modal.html:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog"> 
<div class="modal-content"> 
<div class="modal-header"> 
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button> 
<h4 class="modal-title">  title  </h4> 
</div> 
<div class="modal-body"> 
<p>  body  </p> 
</div> 
<div class="modal-footer"> 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div>
```

1.You can use an Iframe and put it in the modal content place.

like this:

```
<iframe src="myModal.html"></iframe>
```

2.Or if you want to do this only with Jquery you can use load function:

```
$('#container').load('myModal.html', function(data) { 
     $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I like method 2 better. But you should change your answer, put `.modal('show')` inside the callback function of .load(). Like this: `jQuery('#container').load('myModal.html', function(data) {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });`

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look to [jQuery modal](http://jquerymodal.com/) wich accept html as a content. like "myModal01.html"